# Blogdown category pages are showing all posts regardless of category

Tags: r, blogdown

I am trying to add tags to my blogdown site. I added this code to the single.html file [as instructed in blogdown docs](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/master/docs/02-hugo.Rmd)

```
<div class="article-meta">
  <p class="terms">
  {{ range $i := (slice "categories" "tags") }}
  {{ with ($.Param $i) }}
  {{ $i | title }}:
  {{ range $k := . }}
  <a href='{{ relURL (print "/" $i "/" $k | urlize) }}'>{{$k}}</a>
  {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
</p>
  </div>
```

So the categories now show at the bottom of the page. The YAML in my posts looks something like this

```
---
title: Welcome!
author: My name
date: '2017-07-01'
slug: welcome
categories:
  - General

---
```

I have another post with a different category, but both posts show up on both category pages when I click through. I have set relativeurls to true and I am using the default theme. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'll fix it in the default theme (I didn't have categories/tags in mind so I hardcoded something in `list.html`).

Comment: That would be awesome, thanks very much @Yihui . I decided to use blogdown to put up a quick local election news site, so, quite unlike me, I didn't fiddle around with themes or CSS but just used the defaults in this case to get it live quickly. [Except for the logo, which I also had trouble with but I finally came up with something text-based that's not hideous (I thought the title would show on the top banner automatically but it doesn't seem to).]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of the theme (the list was hardcoded to show all posts of a site), and I just [fixed it](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/commit/c1cfac7ca0d23339c4e3633a14dd2d633061b8c2) on Github. You can try to reinstall the theme: https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme

Comment: Thanks again! I've launched my site, and the categories are working now!